# How to find the successor ID of a basic block in LLVM?

Tags: llvm, control-flow-graph

I am trying a traversal of sorts over all the basic blocks in a function. However, I need to find the unique identifier for each basic block so that I can reference it later.

Is there an LLVM API that gives the name/ID of a block?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The "LLVM way" of doing that is using the pointer to the basic block as its unique identifier.

If you need something that will be persistent between runs, I'd say giving the block a unique name (via `setName`) and then searching for it later (using `getName`) is the simplest approach; other options are to create metadata which will map indices to instructions, or inserting special function calls at the beginning of each interesting basic block.